# FType Script omitting "%1" when running

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a .bat file that will set Acrobat DC as the default program for multiple file types, since I need to use this in an office setting with multiple computers after one of my colleagues accidentally deployed Acrobat Reader DC to all the workstations.

What I have currently is:

```
FTYPE Acrobat.Document.2015=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 2015\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe "%1"
ASSOC .pdf=Acrobat.Document.2015
```

but after running the script (as admin), when I enter

```
FTYPE Acrobat.Document.2015
```

to check, it outputs:

```
Acrobat.Document.2015=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 2015\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe ""
```

I'm not sure why the %1 isn't being passed when running the script, as it works fine when I type the entire command out into CMD. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: [Escaping Percents](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html): in a batch-file, use  `%%1` to get literally `%1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I'm not sure why the %1 isn't being passed when running the script

This is because `%1` has a special meaning inside a batch file - it represents a command line argument passed into the batch file:

> A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a
>   batch script:
>
> ```
> C:> MyScript.cmd January 1234 "Some value"
> ```
>
> Arguments can also be passed to a subroutine with CALL:
>
> ```
> CALL :my_sub 2468
> ```
>
> You can get the value of any argument using a `%` followed by it's
>   numerical position on the command line. The first item passed is
>   always `%1` the second item is always `%2` and so on

Source - [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

As you are not calling the batch file with any parameters `%1` is an empty string.

In order to pass a literal `%1` to the `ftype` command you need to [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) the normal meaning of the `%` by using a double `%%` and use `%%1` instead of `%1`.

Note you should also quote the first argument to `ftype` as it contains spaces.

**Modified batch file:**

```
FTYPE Acrobat.Document.2015="C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 2015\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" "%%1"
ASSOC .pdf=Acrobat.Document.2015
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [assoc](http://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) - Display or change the association between a file extension and a fileType
- [ftype](http://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) - Display or change the link between a FileType and an executable program.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was probably a simple error, and this worked for me!